# postLink is not working within datatable in cakephp 3

Tags: javascript, datatable, cakephp-3.0

I am using **datatable** to display my product list. To the last column of the table I added **View**/**Edit**/**Delete** link. **View**/**Edit** are working fine, but **Delete** is not working. I used '***postLink***' to the **Delete** link,

```
<?= $this->AuthUser->postLink('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span><span class="sr-only">' . __('Delete') . '</span>', ['action' => 'delete', 'ID'], ['confirm' => 'Are you sure to delete?', 'escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger delete-btn', 'title' => __('Delete')]) ?>
```

but ***postLink*** is not working. I could not find out the problem.

I am using ***ypnos-web/cakephp-datatables*** to my project.

Here is the **datatable** code of my *index.ctp* file:

```
<?php $this->start('scriptInline'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dt.render.actions = function (data, type, full, meta) {
    var actions = '<?= $this->AuthUser->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span><span class="sr-only">' . __('View') . '</span>', ['action' => 'view', 'ID'], ['escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-default', 'title' => __('View')]) ?>
            <?= $this->AuthUser->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span><span class="sr-only">' . __('Edit') . '</span>', ['action' => 'edit', 'ID'], ['escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-default', 'title' => __('Edit')]) ?>
            <?= $this->AuthUser->postLink('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span><span class="sr-only">' . __('Delete') . '</span>', ['action' => 'delete', 'ID'], ['confirm' => 'Are you sure to delete?', 'escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger delete-btn', 'title' => __('Delete')]) ?>'
    actions = actions.replace(/ID/g, data);
    return actions;
    }

<?php
$options = [
    'ajax' => [
        'url' => $this->Url->build()
    ],
    'data' => $data,
    'deferLoading' => $data->count(),
    'columns' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Products.id',
            'data' => 'id',
            'searchable' => false,
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Products.title',
            'data' => 'title'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Products.description',
            'data' => 'description'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Products.image',
            'data' => 'image'
        ],
        [
            'name' => ['Products.id'],
            'data' => 'id',
            'searchable' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
            'render' =>$this->DataTables->callback('dt.render.actions')
        ],

    ],
    'order' => [0, 'desc'], // order by username
    'columnDefs' => [
        [
            'targets' => 4,
            'orderable' => false,
        ]
    ]
];
echo $this->DataTables->draw('#dataTable', $options, ['class' => 'table table-striped']);
?>

</script>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

My_Controller.php

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $product = $this->Products->get($id);
    if ($this->Products->delete($product)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The {0} has been deleted.', 'Product'));
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The {0} could not be deleted. Please, try again.', 'Product'));
    }
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens when you do it? How is that different from what you expect?

Comment: If I click to the Delete link it should go to my controller > public function delete().
but it do not go to the delete method. and not give any error message. It just stay on the current page with added a # at the end of the url.

Comment: Sounds like you have a JavaScript error somewhere on your page, might be unrelated to this. Check your browser console to see what's going on.